# Count frequency based on multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have multiple columns with VC's funds.

```
df <- data.frame(Company = c("X", "Y","Z"),
                 Valuation = c("10","20","30"),
                 VC.1 = c("Zeev Ventures","Bedrock Capital","Activant Capital"),
                 VC.2 = c("Bedrock Capital","Activant Capital","Zeev Ventures"))
```

| Company | Valuatiion | VC.1 | VC.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 10 | Zeev Ventures | Bedrock Capital |
| Y | 20 | Bedrock Capital | Activant Capital |
| Z | 30 | Activant Capital | Zeev Ventures |

I need calcucalte different statistics for each VC fund. For example

| VC | Total Valuatiion | Total Investments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Zeev Ventures | 40 | 2 |
| Bedrock Capital | 40 | 2 |
| Activant Capital | 50 | 2 |

Comment: Looking for base R solutions?

Comment: @s_baldur, I'm looking for any solution, which fits best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pivot the `VC.1` and `VC.2` columns and get your results with the usual `dplyr` functions:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = c("VC.1", "VC.2"), values_to = "VC") %>%
  group_by(VC) %>%
  summarise(TV = sum(as.numeric(Valuation)), TI = n())

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  VC                  TV    TI
  <chr>            <dbl> <int>
1 Activant Capital    50     2
2 Bedrock Capital     30     2
3 Zeev Ventures       40     2
```

I recommend inspecting the result of the `pivot_longer()` function call alone for a better understanding of why this pivoting step solves the problem of having identifiers in multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to VFreguglia's solution but using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, Valuation := as.numeric(Valuation)]
df[, !"Company"
   ][, melt(.SD, id.vars = "Valuation")
     ][, .(total_val = sum(Valuation), total_inv = .N), by = .(VC = value)]

#                  VC total_val total_inv
#              <char>     <num>     <int>
# 1:    Zeev Ventures        40         2
# 2:  Bedrock Capital        30         2
# 3: Activant Capital        50         2
```

Base R:

```
cols <- grep("^VC", names(df))
df$Valuation <- as.numeric(df$Valuation)
VC <- unlist(df[cols])
df2 <- as.data.frame(table(VC))
df2$total_val <- 
  sapply(df2$VC, \(com) sum(df$Valuation[Reduce("|", lapply(df[cols], \(x) x == com))]))

#                 VC Freq total_val
# 1 Activant Capital    2        50
# 2  Bedrock Capital    2        30
# 3    Zeev Ventures    2        40
```

Another base R:

```
df$Valuation <- as.numeric(df$Valuation)
cols <- grep("^VC", names(df))
grep("^VC", names(df)) |>
  lapply(\(col) setNames(df[c(2, col)], c("val", "VC"))) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _) |>
  aggregate( val ~ VC, FUN = \(x) c(total = sum(x), inv = length(x)))

#                 VC val.total val.inv
# 1 Activant Capital        50       2
# 2  Bedrock Capital        30       2
# 3    Zeev Ventures        40       2
```

Answer (score 2):

With base R, you can use `reshape` + `aggregate`, e.g.,

```
aggregate(
    cbind(totVal = as.numeric(Valuation), totInves = 1) ~ VC,
    reshape(
        df,
        direction = "long",
        idvar = c("Company", "Valuation"),
        varying = -(1:2)
    ),
    sum
)
```

which gives

```
                VC totVal totInves
1 Activant Capital     50        2
2  Bedrock Capital     30        2
3    Zeev Ventures     40        2
```